# I need help on plotting surface through my list of data points

Tags: plotting

I have this data which you can access through pastebin,

http://pastebin.com/6VGiR4dc

I want to draw a cone like surface through these points, which would be hollow on the inside as you could visualize.

When I used ListPointPlot3D, it looks somewhat like this
[image: using ListPointPlot3D]

However when I try to use PointPlot3D, it gives me this weird looking surface. I also tried ListSurfacePlot3D, but that gives me an even weirder looking thing. I asked this question Yesterday, and people suggested increasing Maxpoints for surfaceplot but that didn't work either. My previous question was put on hold because it didn't have enough data. So now i've attached all data. Please help me out, Im new to mathematica...

[image: Using PointPlot3D]

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps[`ConvexHullMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvexHullMesh.html):

```
ch = ConvexHullMesh[pts];
RegionPlot3D[ch, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], Background -> Black, 
 Boxed -> False]
Show[ListPointPlot3D[pts, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.01]}, 
  Background -> Black, Boxed -> False], 
 RegionPlot3D[ch, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]], Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: This is almost perfect, but if you could only find a way to display the coordinate axes? like i have in my question using pointplot3d??

that'd be great!!

Comment: @MuhammadAbbas just  either remove  `Axes->False` or remove `Boxed->False` or both.